# Angular HTTP.jsonp Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: angular, http

```
    $http.jsonp('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson', {'jsonpCallbackParam': 'callback'})
      .then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
  });
```

I'm currently attempting to send a request to find all Jack Johnson audio and video content from the [iTunes API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/SearchExamples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017632-CH6-SW1) using the above code. However, in my console I get the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

The error looks like this [image]

Comment: Your json is bad `{jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}`  Try this instead: `{'jsonpCallbackParam': 'callback'}`. Note the single quote around `jsonpCallbackParam`

Comment: Thanks for spotting. I added the single quotes but I'm still getting the same error about the unexpected token :

Comment: Can u check the formal on jsonlint.com once and confirm